# Add button to top UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have an app which has a UITabBarController as rootviewcontroller.  The UITabBarController has four items.  The four UIViewConotrollers are embedded in UINavigationControllers.  I can add a button or image on the UINavigationController.  However, I have to repeat 4 times on each UINavigationController for the same button or image.  Is it possible I can add a button or image on the top of UITabBarController which is set as rootviewcontroller?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can do it by:

```
UIButton *button = ; // your button
button.frame = CGRect(...); // position on the screen, where you want to have the button

[rootViewController addSubview:button];
```

However, this solution is strongly not recommended.

What you can do instead, is to create an abstract class `MyViewControllerWithButton : UIViewController` which will implement `viewDidAppear:` creation of `UIButton` and adding it to the navigationBar.

All the viewControllers that you use in tab bars will be a subclass of MyViewControllerWithButton.